# Data-binding to singleton source works only on Windows Phone emulator, but not on device

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, data-binding, silverlight-toolkit

I've created a singleton class to store information I want to share globally between controls in a Windows Phone 7 app I'm working on.

Specifically, I'm using a data-binding to sync the `IsExpanded` property between various Silverlight Toolkit ExpanderViews. The problem I'm experiencing is that the value doesn't seem to propagate, but only on a *physical* Windows Phone device...the app works fine on the emulator.

Since all other bindings to sources other than the singleton class in this project are working fine, I've assumed I implemented the binding and/or singleton incorrectly, or am missing something obvious...but every thread on this forum and others I've checked hasn't helped me solve this issue.

The singleton class is as follows:

```
class ControlStateContainer : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static readonly ControlStateContainer _instance = new ControlStateContainer();
    private bool _optionsExpanded = false;

    private ControlStateContainer()
    { }

    public static ControlStateContainer Instance
    {
        get { return _instance; }
    }

    public bool OptionsExpanded
    {
        get { return _optionsExpanded; }
        set
        {
            _optionsExpanded = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("OptionsExpanded");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

And I'm binding the `IsExpanded` property of the ExpanderViews with the following code:

```
Binding _isExpandedBinding = new Binding
{
    Source = ControlStateContainer.Instance,
    Path = new PropertyPath("OptionsExpanded"),
    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
};

expander.SetBinding(ExpanderView.IsExpandedProperty, _isExpandedBinding);
```

The ExpanderViews behave as expected on the emulator, but when I deploy the app to a device the binding no longer seems to work.

I'm still quite new to C# and Windows Phone development in general and fully expect this to be a cringeworthily simple detail I've missed...any ideas?

Comment: is there a specific reason why you are doing the binding in code behind and not XAML?

Comment: Well, since there are many expanders I thought it easier to create them programmatically and then loop over them to set the bindings. This approach works fine for all my other bindings, just not sure why it doesn't in this particular case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the singleton class has to be explicitly declared `public`...now it works on both the emulator and the device.